# chrome_options.binary_location() TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I hope everyone are well.
I'm a new in python and itry alot to run this code but i can't understand what is the problem and how i can solve this.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = raw_input("Enter URL to get visits (With http://): ")
proxy_path = raw_input("Enter path to proxy file:")

with open(proxy_path) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    f.close()

proxies = 0
with open(proxy_path) as infp:
    for line in infp:
       if line.strip():
        proxies += 1

print 'Loaded %d proxies' %proxies    



# For debugging purposes
#print content[run_through]
run_through = 1
while True:
    #print "Start of loop"
    print "Ran %s times" %run_through
    try:
        use_proxy = content[run_through]
    except IndexError:
        print "Out of proxies"
        break
    print "Using: %s" %use_proxy
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' %use_proxy)
    chrome_options.binary_location(value = u"C:\\ProgramFiles\\Google\\Chrome\\chrome.exe")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    #print "Browser started"
   try:
       browser.get(url)
       #print "Opened URL"
       sleep(10)
       browser.find_element_by_id('skip_button').click()
       sleep(10)
       browser.quit()
       #print "Adding one to proxy count"

    except Exception,e:
        print "Skipping proxy. Error occured"
        # For debugging, uncomment line below
        #print str(e)
        browser.quit()
        run_through += 1
        continue

    run_through += 1

    if run_through >= proxies:
        print "No more proxies"
        break

print 'Done!'
```

And i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 40, in <module>
    chrome_options.binary_location(value = u"C:\\ProgramFiles\\Google\\Chrome\\c
hrome.exe")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Hope my questions is clear.

Comment: As the error message (and the domcumentation) says, `chrome_options.binary_location` is a _string_, not a function. You're trying to call it, which makes no sense.

Comment: @l4mpi So, how i can solve my problem.?

Comment: By reading the documentation and using common sense as well as logical reasoning. I have no idea of selenium but I'd guess you want to simply set the value, using a plain old assignment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're doing `chrome_options.binary_location()` but binary_location is a string, not a function.

After looking over [the source code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/options.py#40), it appears that we've just got a getter and a setter here. @l4mpi appears to be correct - simply doing `chrome_options.binary_location = "C:\\ProgramFiles\\Google\\Chrome\\chrome.exe"` ought to work.

You can find the Selenium docs here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

---

Old (wrong) answer:

What you probably wanted here was `chrome_options.setBinary("C:\\ProgramFiles\\Google\\Chrome\\chrome.exe")`, as [referenced in the docs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities).

Comment: Thank you for this help but now i get this error `AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'setBinary'` in `line 40` => `chrome_options.setBinary("C:\\ProgramFiles\\Google\\Chrome\\chrome.exe")`

Comment: @yuyb0y OK, I've done some more research and edited my answer.

Comment: But can i use `FireFox` instead of chrome? and how?

Comment: @yuyb0y I assume you'd use `FirefoxOptions` and `webdriver.Firefox`?

Comment: Putting this here as an update for anyone in who might need help with this now:

`options.setChromeBinaryPath("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\Application\\chrome.exe")`