# Trouble calling the location for Google Chrome in code

Tags: python

I'm trying to open the web browser, and one line of code is giving me problems

options.binary_location("C:/Users/Calhoun/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome")

I've been eliminating my problems one by one on this site but I cant find a solution to this one. Whenever I run the code, it says:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

No where in my code do I have str, so it's not a problem of me changing something. The full directory for Chrome is

C:\Users\Calhoun\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

before it branches off into a bunch of folders.

What can I do to make this error go away

Comment: Please provide more context as to what code you tried and what you expect to happen. Opening a browser in python may just mean calling the command line for the command in the path, but it's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `str` is the parameter you passed in to your `options.binary_location(...)` function.

It was not "callable" because the compiler most likely could not find that `str` object in your directory. In this case, I believe it didn't know what to do with that file your provided, so it threw that error at you.

I believe if you want to call the directory of chrome that will open the browser, that is equivilant to calling the .exe file, known as the **executable file**. Try to find the directory of the google.exe file, copy that path, and try inserting it into that function.

You can also find a more detailed answer here, in a similar post: [chrome_options.binary_location() TypeError: 'str' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863115/chrome-options-binary-location-typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable)